# Typescript can't find dependency moment definition file

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, momentjs, typescript1.8

I've been having problems trying to resolve a dependency in my `form.ts` file:

```
  import moment  = require('moment');

  class LocationViewModel {

    public Id: number;
    public Name: string;

    constructor(id: number, name: string)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }

 }

 class SearchViewModel {
     public fromLocations: Array<LocationViewModel> = [];
     public loLcations: Array<LocationViewModel> =  [];
     public date: moment;

     constructor() {

     }
  }
```

When I run `node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc` I get this error:

```
 error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'moment'.
```

My moment dependency lives in node_modules/@types. Kindly see attached image

[image]

This is what's inside my tsconfig.json file:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./built/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types" : ["jquery", "lodash", "moment"]
  },
  "files": [
    "./src/require-config.ts",
    "./src/form.ts"
  ]
 }
```